# Installing modules using pip fails

Tags: pip, python-3.6

I am trying to install numpy using pip3.
This is the command I used:

pip3 install numpy (also tried with sudo but it gives same error)

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 33, in vendored
    __import__(vendored_name, globals(), locals(), level=0)
ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.distro'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==9.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip3')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 561, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2631, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2291, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2297, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 67, in <module>
    vendored("distro")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 36, in vendored
    __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/distro-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/distro.py", line 1051, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/distro-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/distro.py", line 595, in __init__
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/distro-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/distro.py", line 932, in _get_lsb_release_info
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'lsb_release -a' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

This is the problem when I try to install any Python module
This was working fine till just a few days ago.

I tried deleting pip altogether and then reinstalling it. But I get the same error
None of the packages get installed via pip now.

I have python 3.6.5

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python pip doesn't work on Linux mint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40710326/python-pip-doesnt-work-on-linux-mint)

Comment: That problem doesn't seem to be resolved, and re-installing the OS is my last option, the very last resort

Answer (score 1):

i had this problem too.
i solved it by installing anaconda and installing all ml packages

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after setting the system default to Python3.5. Oddly, it would appear that `pip3` needs Python2.7 to function; running `# update-alternatives --config python` and selecting Python2.7 got `pip3` working again for me. I just installed `pygame` this way, and it works as expected after switching the system default back to Python3.5. This is on [Devuan](https://devuan.org) ASCII and

```sh
$ python --version
Python 3.5.3
$ pip3 --version 
...
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'lsb_release -a' returned non-zero exit status 1

$ sudo update-alternatives --config python
There are 2 choices for the alternative python (providing /usr/bin/python).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/python3.5   2         auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python2.7   1         manual mode
* 2            /usr/bin/python3.5   2         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1

$ python --version
Python 2.7.13
$ pip3 --version 
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.5)
```

**Edit:** On Raspbian Stretch `pip3` works with Python3.5 as the system default, so this is clearly not the full story:

```sh
$ python --version
Python 3.5.3
$ pip3 --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.5)
```